# ListView inline highlight like Windows 7's search highlighting

Tags: windows, user-interface

When you perform a search in Windows 7, each match has the search term decorated with a rather fancy bordered yellow highlight.  Is there a way to duplicate this in my own software?

For example, the .NET framework's ListView control needs a call to SetWindowTheme to "explorer" in order to display selected cells and other details the way Vista does rather than flat blue.  Is there some process to send highlight information for each item?

While I'm using the .NET framework, I am comfortable being introduced to any Win32/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard control for this. Explorer uses a custom control, not a listview.